# How to colourize each text content of a row in table?

Tags: tables, formatting, color

I do not want to highlight the content of the cells. Rather, I want to colour the text of each cell of some particular rows of the table. I can do it by using `\textcolor{}{}`. But I have a large table. So, it will not be feasible to use this method in each cell. Is there any alternative to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have a command `\RowStyle` to apply formatting commands to all the cells of a row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}
one & two & three \\
\RowStyle[color=blue]{\itshape}
apple & pig & cartoon \\
TeX & LaTeX & LuaLaTeX 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

`tabularray` package separates formatting from data by using options, and formatting can cascade.

[image: tblr]

NWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}



\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {ccc},
    row{2, 3, 6, 8} = {fg=blue, font=\itshape}, 
    cell{3,5}{2,3} = {fg=red},
    cell{5}{2} = {fg=black},
    }
one & two & three \\
dapple & dig & darter \\
dapple & dog & darter \\
TeX & LaTeX & LuaLaTeX \\
zTeX & zLaTeX & yLuaLaTeX \\ 
dibble & dug & darker \\
TeX & LaTeX & LuaLaTeX \\
double & dagg & dorker \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```